# Using virtualenv

Tags: django, virtualenv

I've been reading up on using virtualenv for django projects and i just wanted a bit of confirmation.

After installing virtualenv via sudo pip install virtualenv. You type in the command virtualenv ENV to create a virtual --no-site-packages ENV directory named ENV that only has the pythong standard library in it.

Next you go to ./ENV/bin/ directory to install the latest version of Django.

To use older versions of Django, simply create another virtualenv and install a different version of Django in /bin/.

Please let me know if my logic is correct! Thank you!

Comment: `--no-site-packages` is the default option in newer versions of virtualenv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds right.

Do you mean you do `source ./ENV/bin/activate` and then do `pip install django==VERSION` to install the specified version of django? You do have to activate the virtualenv for it work.

Comment: yea that is something i forgot sorry!

Comment: I was also wondering if this video gave a proper tutorial

[link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bpv0-kFlXkM)

Comment: Looks ok to me. Try `virtualenvwrapper` by all means, it makes the process much smoother. Relevant to your process, with `virtualenvwrapper` you do not get the system site-packages by default.